# Opening gallery as app programmatically

Tags: android

I want to open gallery when user presses a button. The code I use is this:

```
Intent resimGaleri = new Intent();
resimGaleri.setType("image/*");
resimGaleri.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Main.this.startActivity(resimGaleri);
```

However, in this code, when user presses the button to open gallery, Android asks 'Complete action using', but I want it to open gallery directly without asking. I can do that with the following code:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.android.gallery3d"));
```

But I'm not sure if **all** devices use 'com.android.gallery3d' or not. Is it possible or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: You should certainly not force users to use specific gallery application, just let them choose from `image/*` providers they have installed. If there is no other provider than Gallery application, it will be opened without prompt.

Comment: But our program needs to force users to use specific gallery which is Android's default gallery.

Comment: Not every android installation has default Android gallery, think of branded ROMs eg. from HTC, Verizon, ... and think about Cyanogenmod installation. You can check if the specific gallery app is present, and run it, otherwise give user the option to choose.

Comment: I see your point. Is it possible to choose default Android gallery if firstly, and as you said if it doesn't exist, is it possible to ask 'Complete action using'?

Answer (score 2):

Not all the devices have com.android.gallery3d, while most of them do. You can query the package manager by the intent action VIEW with MIME type image/* to get a list of activities. And then look through the list to find the correct one.

```
final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, null);
i.setType("image/*");
final List<ResolveInfo> apps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
if(apps != null) {
    for(ResolveInfo info : apps) {
        if(info.resolvePackageName!=null && info.resolvePackageName.contains("gallery3d")) {//Maybe use more strict condition
             //This is the target you want
             //startActivity(XXXX);
             return;
        }
    }
    //Target not found
    //Start the first match or handle your exception here
} else {
//Handle exception
}
```

Comment: I see. Can you give an example through your 2nd clause?

Comment: Dummy sample added for your reference

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code:
(it tested code not view massage ask you).

```
// select a file
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
```